# pytest: Just look for ImportErrors

Tags: python, pytest

Often when testing, pytest runs a bunch of tests, and then fails on some silly ImportError because of refactoring.

Is there a way to ask pytest to just to an initial pass where it tries to import everything and tells you if there's an ImportError, before running any tests?

Comment: Have you considered using an IDE/linter to keep track of these issues?

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
py.test src/tests --collect-only
```

This will just find the tests without running them, and will report any syntax errors, etc. Doesn't seem to detect import errors though